# Change default storage location to external SD card in Micromax A121 Canvas Elanza 2

Tags: external-sd, 4.1-jelly-bean, micromax

Recently I have purchased Micromax A121 Canvas Elanza 2. I have used a 16GB External SD card. I want to change the default storage Internal SD card to External SD Card without installing any apps.

I googled and read some blogs. They are saying go to Settings -> Storage -> Change your default storage. But I saw on my mobile there are no options for set default storage.

Comment: The details [about this phone](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/micromax-canvas-elanza-2-1587) states that it is running 4.3 JB while you've tagged it as 4.1 JB. So which Android version are you using? And, is the device rooted?

Comment: you wanna make it your default storage for what ? for storing pictures ,for installing apps  ? or for something else ?

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf I want set default storage without installing any apps

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf I sas Micromax different  model there have storage in `Settings->Storage` but Micromax Canvas Elanza have not that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could move installed applications to SD card or could install a ROM with App2SD or Data2SD. But by default, they'll stay on your phone's internal memory.

Try [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD). I'm using it, and I can say I'm pleased with it.

Comment: I want to set default storege. If i capture photo then photo will be saved in the External SD card.

Comment: @Chinu go to camera settings and then change the degault storage location of photos

Comment: I am not asking only for camera. What ever i want like Bluetooth, Download file from internet, Camera photos,  WhatsApp Videos and images etc.

Answer (score -1):

Install a terminal emulator and bind-mount. That seems to be the only way possible, in your case.

Comment: What is bind-mount to a person unknown to commands (consider some future readers when answering), and what should one do with it?

Comment: I was unsure of the fact that it would work without root access so I didn't elaborate. Will do so now, @Firelord.